# How to change user password?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

How to change user password for logged in user (and any field in user profile) if I use Silverlight Business Application?

Comment: Please give more details on the question. What mechanism do you use to store and manage passwords? Is it Membership provider?

Comment: Yes, it use default Membership provider. All application's settings by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I created Domain Service with only one method:

```
[EnableClientAccess()] 
public class DomainChangePassword : DomainService 
{ 
 [ServiceOperation] 
 public bool UserChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword) 
 { 
  if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, oldPassword)) 
  { 
   MembershipUser memUser = Membership.GetUser(userName); 
   return memUser.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword); 
  } 
  return false; 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in mechanism to change password in Silverlight.
You need to implement your own service for that.

For example:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class SecurityService : ISecurityService
{
    public bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        return Membership.Provider.ChangePassword(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, oldPassword, newPassword);
    }
    ...
}
```

If this answers your question, please "mark it as answer".

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class SecurityService : ISecurityService
{
    public bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        return Membership.Provider.ChangePassword(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, oldPassword, newPassword);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please, elaborate a little bit more.